Preserving the font size in exporting images
I am trying to make a video by generating many images of a process, exporting them to the disk by the Export command in the PNG format, and finally making a video with FFmpeg.
My images have a title on the top with the values of the parameters. I optimized the font size of the title. When I show these images in the Mathematica notebook and save them by rightclicking and choosing "Save graphics as", I obtain saved images that look the same as in the Mathematica notebook.
However, when I save the images with the Export command, the titles have a much smaller font.
Why does this happen and how it can be fixed? I was unable to find any discussion of this problem. Apparently, it is supposed that the exported images should be OK and there should be no such problem.
I am using Mathematica 14 on Windows 11 but I also have earlier versions installed.
Dmitry

Could you post an example with code? With a plot, for example ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "Title", ImageSize -> 200] I get nearly identical images with "Save graphic as" and Export.

I made the images with ListPlot[,,,,,ImageSize->FrameSize] and FrameSize=800 defined above. However, in the Export command I used Export[....,ImageSize->{1334,1350}] that was a mistake. Now I am using xport[....,ImageSize->{FrameSize,FrameSize},ImageResolution->72] that works fine.

Why the numbers {1334,1350}? First, I exported images without size and resolution. I assumed the size would be the same as in the image generation. I haven't looked at the sizes of the exported images and tried to make a video with ffmpeg. However, I've got an error because not all frames had even dimensions that were required by ffmpeg. The dimensions fluctuated plus/minus one pixel. Still, I was not alerted by the images being larger than intended, and I simply added the command ImageSize->{1334,1350} preserving the size of exported images but forcing their dimensions even.

Sorry for the trouble, I have found the answer. In the Export command, I defined ImageSize larger than ImageSize of the generated image, this is why the font size in the output looked small.
This is a silly problem, I know, but my attention was distracted by other problems with making videos. I will report on them in another post.
Dmitry
